# MYSQL Não Inicia

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

Olá!

Anteriormente realizei a migração do meu banco de dados de um diretório para outro dentro do próprio servidor (/var/ para /mnt/) por falta de espaço.

Só que ao iniciar o servidor novamente, depois de ter alterado o /etc/my.cnf com o diretório correto ele me retorna este erro:

```
$ systemctl start mysqld

Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

E ao executar o comando de status do systemctl no serviço do mysqld ele me retorna:

```
$ systemctl status mysqld.service

mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Ter 2019-07-16 09:34:44 -03; 44s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 31923 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 31899 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 31923 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "SERVER_BOOTING"
    Error: 13 (Permissão negada)

Jul 16 09:34:43 srvepl.cettro.local systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
Jul 16 09:34:44 srvepl.cettro.local systemd[1]: mysqld.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 16 09:34:44 srvepl.cettro.local systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Jul 16 09:34:44 srvepl.cettro.local systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Jul 16 09:34:44 srvepl.cettro.local systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

Se for erro de permissão, como libero para o server aceitar tal diretório?

Obs:
    Estou usando o CentOS 7

Obrigado!!

Comment: Fala, galera! Consegui resolver o problema... Parece que o SELINUX tava travando a iniciação, criando algum tipo de restrição. Para quem tiver o mesmo problema basta utilizar: `$ setenforce 0` Valeu!!